# angular中 @HostListener('window:load') Ie11 does not support it. How do you fix it?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

#### angular9

```
@HostListener('window:load', ['$event']) 
onLoad(event: Event) {
    console.log(123);
}
```

Ie11 does not support
Anyone know the solution?
(ie11不支持，有知道解决方案的吗？)

Comment: I rather wonder what do you need it for. Angular itself is loaded when the window is loaded

Comment: I need an element in app.components.ts to wait until window.onload does something to show or hide

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we can use Element.addEventListener method as an alternative to HostListener.

Example:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[onlyMyBacon]'})
export class OnlyMyBacon implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.onMouseEnter);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.removeEventListener('mouseenter', this.onMouseEnter);
  }

  onMouseEnter() {
     alert("Don't touch my bacon!")
  }
}
```

Reference:

[Four ways of listening to DOM events in Angular (Part 2: @HostListener)](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/four-ways-of-listening-to-dom-events-in-angular-part-2-hostlistener-1b66d45b3e3d)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but now I need to remove the loading animation when the page has finished loading. So what I'm going to do now is if I say IE I'm going to just remove the animation from ngOnInit

Comment: If possible for you then try to use the code like this may help you to fulfill your requirement. angular.element(function () {
    console.log('page loading completed');
});